# RangeError [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: File size (3472064213) is greater than 2 GB

Tags: node.js, json

```
const entries = require("../rootsiir.sql")
const objId = 9
const filteredObj = entries.filter((obj) => obj.tc === objId)[0]
const name = filteredObj.name
const id = filteredObj.id

console.log(name)
console.log(age)
```

I have this code which is a search JSON file.

But ı am taking this error:

`RANGEERROR [ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE]: FILE SIZE (3472064213) IS GREATER THAN 2 GB-NODE.JS`

My JSON file 2.5GB. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js doesn't support `require()`ing files over 2.5GB because they can't fit in a single buffer. Instead, you'll need to open the file as a stream and parse the stream as JSON.

You could implement this yourself, but libraries already exist to do it. I suggest using the [`big-json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json) package. Here's the example from the README:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const json = require('big-json');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('big.json');
const parseStream = json.createParseStream();

parseStream.on('data', function(obj) {
    // => receive reconstructed object
});

readStream.pipe(parseStream);
```

Comment: does this also apply to sql connect?

Comment: @Kaya I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but the 2.5GB limit applies to reading any file in node.js. If you ever need to read a file of any type over 2.5GB, you'll need to use a stream.

Comment: @Kaya Have you been able to test my answer?